# What is sense of NodeJS modules without any exports?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

If there's any. Im not really into web technologies, but have to understand some awful code written by someone else in Node.

Comment: Your question lacks an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please [edit] one in.

Comment: If the module is just meant to be executed, not used by other apps/tools, why would it need to export anything?

Comment: My example is a little long and im not exactly sure how to shorten it...

If it's meant to be executed why do we call it 'module', not an app or something?

Comment: Because all node.js apps can become modules by using npm init and npm publish.

Comment: OK, but is there any reason for making a module from a common app?

Comment: Yes, for example, my express app. I have it built as a module, and it doesn't auto-boot if it is included AS a module so that i can pull it into another express app and attach it as a router if i need to do so in the future.

Comment: Exporting can also help with unit testing, deployments, and self-documenting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All node.js apps are npm modules once you execute npm init. After that point, you can publish the module by executing npm publish assuming you gave it a unique name in the package.json.

If the app isn't meant to return anything, then there is no need to export anything. However, it's almost always worth exporting *something* to allow for unit testing deeper than just starting the app as an http server and sending it requests.

It is also sometimes useful to modify the way your app runs based on whether it is being required as a module or executed as an app. For example, say i have an express rest api server. I can run it as a standalone server on `api.example.com`, and then *require* it into another application and run it from that application directly to avoid CORS issues without having to duplicate code or deal with git submodules, instead I simply npm install the api into the application that needs it and attach it just like you would a router. `www.example.com/api`

```
app.use('/api', require('@myusername/api.example.com'))
```